# MySQL database concept for photo gallery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table for storing photo information:

```
CREATE TABLE foto (
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
id_galerie int(11) NOT NULL,
filename varchar(255) NOT NULL,
sort_nr int(11) NOT NULL default 1,
UNIQUE KEY (id_galerie, sort_nr),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I need to auto increment the column **sort_nr**, but only in terms of one **id_galerie**.
So I tried this insert query:

```
INSERT INTO foto (id_galerie, filename)
VALUES
(1, 'filename'),
(1, 'another filename'),
(1, 'anothername'),
(1, 'another value')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sort_nr = sort_nr+1
```

but it threw an error (#1062 - Duplicate entry '1-2' for key 'id_galerie').
How can I force the **sort_nr** to auto increment if the key is not unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ON DUPLICATE KEY checks for primary key, not for unique Index, that's why you see your error. Not sure, that it's even possible without extra query. But you can do it with INSERT INTO SELECT:

```
   INSERT INTO foto (filename, id_galerie, sort_nr)
   SELECT 'filename', 1, (SELECT IFNULL(max(sort_nr) + 1,1) 
        FROM foto WHERE id_galerie = 1) AS `SortNumber`
```

Comment: @lineman Race conditions will happen here if you are on InnoDB engine... because off the MAX calculation.. generating your own auto_increment like this is NOT advised

Comment: @Raymond I'll do this insert query only for one row at a time. Then it won't be a problem, will it?